# Custom module versioning

Tags: 8

I'm writing some custom modules (for a customer), but as expected their are showed in error in update dashboard (/admin/reports/updates): "No version available"

I was wondering if there's any way to tell Drupal that these module belong to another webservice to check for latest updates. So I can manage my module versioning and be aware quickly if some of my module are up to date or not.

I searched a lot about it but no result so far, if this is a duplicate feel free to point it out so I can check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Drupal assumes that any installed module or theme is hosted on drupal.org. This means that, if you are using a custom module (which is probably not hosted on drupal.org), Drupal will return the error you are seeing because it doesn't find any information about the module you are using, on drupal.org.

If you just want to stop Drupal from looking for a module updates, normally because you are using a different method to update it, or because the module is not hosted on drupal.org (for example, a custom module you have on your computer, on Git, Gitlab, or similar services) you can implement [`hook_update_projects_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21update%21update.api.php/function/hook_update_projects_alter/8.6.x).

```
function custom_module_update_projects_alter(&$projects) {
  // Hide a site-specific module from the list.
  unset($projects['custom_module']);
}
```

With this example code, the *custom_module* module is hiding itself, but a module can hide any module. For example, if I had a *custom_core* module that is a dependency for every custom module I use on my site, I would implement the hook using code similar to this.

```
function custom_core_update_projects_alter(&$projects) {
  // Hide all the site-specific modules from the list.
  unset($projects['custom_user_data']);
  unset($projects['custom_entities']);
  unset($projects['custom_spam_prevention']);
}
```

If you want Drupal checks for updates on a site that is not drupal.org, then the .info.yml file for the module needs to contain the following line. (See the code of the [`UpdateFetcher`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21update%21src%21UpdateFetcher.php/class/UpdateFetcher/8.6.x) class, which is the class that fetches project information from remote locations.)

```
project status url: http://example.org/project-history
```

In this case, for a module using my_module as machine name, Drupal will fetch the information about Drupal 8 releases of the module from http://example.org/project-history/my_module/8.x.

Notice also that:

- If the .info.yml file also contains a `project: my_custom_project` line, Drupal will check for information about Drupal 8 releases of the module from 
  http://example.org/project-history/my_custom_project/8.x, not http://example.org/project-history/my_module/8.x (This is useful when a module is a sub-module of another module, and both are packaged in the same file.)
- Drupal expects that http://example.org/project-history/my_module/8.x returns XML data that follows a specific format; you can see for example what drupal.org returns for the Date module (https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/date/8.x)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <project xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <title>Date</title>
    <short_name>date</short_name>
    <dc:creator>vijaycs85</dc:creator>
    <type>project_module</type>
    <api_version>8.x</api_version>
    <project_status>unsupported</project_status>
    <link>https://www.drupal.org/project/date</link>
    <terms>
      <term>
        <name>Projects</name>
        <value>Modules</value>
      </term>
      <term>
        <name>Maintenance status</name>
        <value>Actively maintained</value>
      </term>
      <term>
        <name>Development status</name>
        <value>Under active development</value>
      </term>
    </terms>
    <releases>
      <release>
        <name>date 8.x-1.x-dev</name>
        <version>8.x-1.x-dev</version>
        <tag>8.x-1.x</tag>
        <version_major>1</version_major>
        <version_extra>dev</version_extra>
        <status>published</status>
        <release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/date/releases/8.x-1.x-dev</release_link>
        <download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/date-8.x-1.x-dev.tar.gz</download_link>
        <date>1380568703</date>
        <mdhash>f36524e70ed83fe7f2812d3768a337c0</mdhash>
       <filesize>164918</filesize>
       <files>
         <file>
           <url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/date-8.x-1.x-dev.tar.gz</url>
           <archive_type>tar.gz</archive_type>
           <md5>f36524e70ed83fe7f2812d3768a337c0</md5>
           <size>164918</size>
           <filedate>1380568703</filedate>
         </file>
         <file>
           <url>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/date-8.x-1.x-dev.zip</url>
           <archive_type>zip</archive_type>
           <md5>781eb8cb238ed8649c93f0e8e2b9e778</md5>
           <size>232819</size>
           <filedate>1380568703</filedate>
         </file>
       </files>
       <security>Dev releases are not covered by Drupal security advisories.</security>
     </release>
   </releases>
  ```

  - Not all the information provided is required, but for each release there must be a URL for the archive containing the module code, which is used from Drupal to download and copy the module on the site server.

As side note, updating a module files with Composer would be the first step to update the module. Drupal still needs to invoke the update hooks the module provide, and update the module information it stores in its database tables (and cache).

Comment: great tips I did not know!

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the docs. See [Creating custom modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules) and then the chapter about [Prepare a Module skeleton](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/prepare-a-module-skeleton) which will lead you to this example module on GitHub: https://github.com/sidharrell/D8HWexample

**hello_world.info.yml**

```
name: Hello World Module
description: Creates a page showing "Hello World".
package: Custom
type: module
version: 1.0
core: 8.x
```

I guess you left out `version` (which is optional). Simply add it and you should get rid of the error.

---

> I was wondering if there's any way to tell Drupal that these module
>   belong to another webservice to check for latest updates.

Well, yes, with Composer. You could start [Using Composer to manage Drupal sites](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies), most likely with this template: https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

You now can include GitHub-hosted repos pretty easily. Here comes an extremely simplified example `composer.json` that includes `MYMODULE` hosted on GitHub. The manually added type `drupal-custom-module` and the added directory take care of the rest. You may additionally add that module to your `.gitignore` now.

```
{
    "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "MYMODULE",
                "version": "1.2.3",
                "type": "drupal-custom-module",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/john_doe/MYMODULE.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "tags/1.2.3"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "davidbarratt/custom-installer": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.2",
        "drupal/core": "~8.4",
        "drush/drush": "~9.0",
        "MYMODULE": "^1.2.3"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ],
        "files": ["load.environment.php"]
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        },
        "custom-installer": {
            "drupal-custom-module": "web/modules/custom/{$name}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I guess you left out version (which is optional). Simply add it and you should get rid of the error."
The version was specified in the .info.yml file, I think it's just because Drupal cannot retrieve the version from Drupal's public repositories

"Well, yes, with Composer."

This could do the job except that will not show the update status in the Drupal admin update page like other modules does.

Actually those 5 custom modules are part of a custom Drupal profile I made for my customers and are bundled and shipped with this profile.

Comment: There is a way to stop Drupal complaining with _Version available_ and make Drupal check for updates on a site that is not drupal.org. I will write an answer when I find any reference for Drupal 8.